# Two passthroughs the same htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect traffic for files/dirs that do not exist, however my router does something strange with uris that have two filenames. So I want to explicitly change the uri example:

`https://example.com/testsite/index.php` => `https://example.com/testsite?returnPath=/index.php`

Then internally, I would redirect to `https://example.com/new/index.php/testsite`

my root structure looks like so:

```
-web:
    .htaccess
    -new:
         index.php
```

My  htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !returnPath=*
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]*)/(.*)$ /$1?returnPath=/$2 [QSA,NC,R=302,L] #explicit redirect (what other flags do I use here?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /new/index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Obviously leaving in the `L` flag in the first Rule will write the redirect without processing any other Rules.

But leaving it out, processes the the second Rule also but doesn't change the shown uri

Comment: An external redirection is _always_ executed immediately. It makes no difference if you add a `L` or an `END` flag.

Comment: And what is `L=301` meant to do?

Comment: That was just supposed to be `L`, apologies